# Из базы данных отправляется только первая строка

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

В чем проблема: в таблице находится две строки, я из неё должен по очереди взять одну строку, взять URL, скачать то что находится на этом сайте и отобразить в нужном мне виде. Проблема в том, что берется только одна строка из таблицы, вторую он не воспринимает.

**Вид**
[image: приложение работает, но не полностью выдает информацию]

**Код контроллера**

```
    public class RSSFeedController : Controller
{
    SourceContext db = new SourceContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string RSSURL, string RSSName)
    {
        SourceContext db = new SourceContext();




        foreach (var url in db.Sources.Where(c => c.id != null).Select(c => c.URL))
        {
            WebClient wclient = new WebClient();
            string RSSData = wclient.DownloadString(url);



            var fromEncodind = Encoding.Default;
            var bytes = fromEncodind.GetBytes(RSSData);
            var toEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            RSSData = toEncoding.GetString(bytes);


            XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(RSSData);



            var RSSFeedData = (from x in xml.Descendants("item")
                               select new RSSFeed
                               {
                                   Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
                                   Link = (string)x.Element("link"),
                                   RSSName = (string)x.Element("Name"),
                                   PubDate = (string)x.Element("pubDate")
                               });


            ViewBag.RSSFeed = RSSFeedData;

           // return View();
        }




        return View();

    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Там где я скачиваю файл и присваиваю ему RSSData он должен смотреть все строки у которых id не равно 0 и дальше идти по коду, но он использует только первую строку таблицы. Я пытался через foreach(var b in db.Sources), но он качал два раза один и тот же файл.

БД: [image: БД:]
Данные в таблице:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вьюха**

```
        @model IEnumerable<BDParser.Models.Sources>
        <head>
            <meta encoding="UTF-8" />
            <link class="link">
        </head>

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";

        }
        <br />
        <h2>RSS Feed</h2>
        <hr />
        <br />
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {                
            <br />               
        }
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Publish Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (ViewBag.URL == null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in ViewBag.RSSFeed)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="@item.Link">@item.Title</a></td>
                            <td>@item.RSSName</td>

                            <td>@item.PubDate</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }




            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Не пойму в чем проблема.
Я относительно недавно этим занимаюсь, прошу максимально понятно описывать, то что вы напишите

Comment: `Select(c => c.URL).FirstOrDefault()` как бы намекает - взять первую запись

Comment: а как переделать чтобы работало? Я знаю что из-за этого он выводит только первую строку, но без FirstOrDefault() компилятор ругается.

Comment: `string RSSData` переделать на `var RSSData`, тогда в этой переменной у вас будет список (убрать `.FirstOrDefault()` тоже не забудьте). Дальше вам надо сделать цикл, которым будете обходить каждый элемент в списке и делать всю остальную логику.

Comment: если я убираю `.FirstOrDefault()` появляется ошибка `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' to 'string'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EvgeniyZ** говорит о том, что надо убрать `FirstOrDefault()` и пройти `db.Sources.Where(c => c.id != null).Select(c => c.URL)` циклом:

```
foreach(var url in db.Sources.Where(c => c.id != null).Select(c => c.URL))
{
  string RSSData = wclient.DownloadString(url);
  // Какая-то логика
}
```

Comment: в дебагере видно что он идет по всем строкам таблицы, но теперь появилась другая проблема. Я закрываю цикл перед `return View();` и получается что цикл проходит несколько раз по логике, а отправляет во View только последний результат

Comment: @ДмитрийФадин Покажите код? Возможно вы просто каждую итерацию цикла просто переписываете один и тот же экземпляр класса и в итоге отправляется только один результат

Comment: изменил код контроллера в вопросе, как он сейчас есть, я посмотрел с помощью отладчика что он каждый раз изменяет RSSData, но передает только последний

Comment: @ДмитрийФадин Смотрите как у вас происходит. Вы кладёте в ViewBag.RSSFeed данные на одной итерации цикла. Затем на другой итерации вы их переписываете, и так каждую итерацию. В итоге на вьюшку попадают данные из последней итерации. Я предполагаю вам нужно в ViewBag.RSSFeed класть сформированный список новостей. 
Т.е. вы будете делать что-то типо ViewBag.RSSFeed.Add(RSSFeedData)

Comment: Да, я понял что так это и работает, буду разбираться, спасибо